# How to configure AVCaptureSession for high res still images and low res (video) preview?

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'd like to capture high resolution still images using `AVCaptureSession`. Therefore `AVCaptureSession` preset is set to `Photo`.

This is working well so far. On an iPhone 4 the final still image resolution is at its maximum of 2448x3264 pixels and the preview (video) resolution is 852x640 pixels.

Now, because the preview frames are analyzed to detect objects in the scene, I'd like to lower their resolution. How can this be done?
I've tried to set `AVVideoSettings` with a lower width/height to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, but this leads to the following error message:

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:] - videoSettings dictionary contains one or more unsupported (ignored) keys: (AVVideoHeightKey, AVVideoWidthKey
```

So it seems this is not the right approach to configure the size of the preview frames received by `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` / `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`. Do you have any ideas how the resolution of the preview frames can be configured?

Any advise is welcome,
Thank you.

Comment: You could get an image from buffer and resize the image to an extent that won't affect detecting objects.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I've already tried that, but the performance to convert the raw data into a format supported by the CV library (the library that handles object detection in the scene) is also quite cpu/memory intense. So my preferred approach would be to tell iOS to reduce the data of the preview frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the records: I ended up configuring `AVCaptureSession` in preset `Low` while aiming the camera. As soon as the shutter is triggered, the app switches to preset `Photo`, performs a focus run and takes the picture. This way it takes between 1 and 2.5 seconds to take a picture, which isn't that great, but it's at least a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify the settings manually, you need to set `activeFormat` on the `AVCaptureDevice`. This will be implicitly set the session preset to `AVCaptureSessionPresetInputPriority`.

The `activeFormat` takes a [`AVCaptureDeviceFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDeviceFormat_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)AVCaptureDeviceFormat) but you can only take one from the list of `AVCaptureDevice.formats`. You'll need to go through the list and find one that fits your needs. Specifically, check that `highResolutionStillImageDimensions` is high enough for desired still capture and `formatDescription` (which needs to be inspected with `CMFormatDescription*` functions, e.g., [`CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMFormatDescription/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions)) matches your desired preview settings.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. It seems the high resolution still image is just marginally bigger than the video preview. Here are some numbers of the lowest supported video resolutions and their 'high' still image resolutions:
Video: 192x144 - Still image: 192x192,
Video: 352x288 - Still image: 352x352,
Video: 480x360 - Still image: 480x480. Looks like it doesn't work this way. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To lower the size of the output of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` you can set the bitrate to be lower thus producing a small sample size.

commonly used keys for `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` are:

```
AVVideoAverageBitRateKey
AVVideoProfileLevelKey
AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey
AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey
```

For example:

```
private static let videoCompressionOptionsMedium = [AVVideoAverageBitRateKey : 1750000,
                                                    AVVideoProfileLevelKey : AVVideoProfileLevelH264BaselineAutoLevel,
                                                    AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey : Int(30),
                                                    AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey : Int(30)]
```

Comment: Are you sure that those settings would effect the resolution of the preview frames?

Comment: No but the resolution doesn't effect the output size as much as bitrate does .. which i believe to be your issue as it seems you only want to reduced resolution to reduce size.